# How does a solid planet with an atmosphere in empty space cool down?

Tags: thermodynamics

Imagine that magically a solid planet appears in outer space. It doesn't rotate and there is an atmosphere present around the sphere, which consists of various kinds of atoms and molecules, which don't react with each other and neither with the planet. The planet itself is made of a uniform material, capable of conducting and radiating heat. At the moment of appearance, the temperature of the planet and its atmosphere are equal (and is thus such that all the elements of the atmosphere are gaseous). Because no sun (star) is present the atmosphere is one without wind. How will the cooling down take place?

Comment: "consists of various kinds of atoms and molecules, which don't react with each other and neither with the planet" - at the very least they interact gravitationally and with regular gas pressure.

Comment: "The planet itself is made of a uniform material, capable of conducting and radiating heat" - I believe you have just answered yourself here

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Well, I agree with @JanDvorak ☺️ You have answered the question yourself: **Radiation**

Comment: the basic law is black body radiation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Answer (score 2):

The atmosphere radiates infrared radiation into space. The atmosphere is heated from below by further radiation and conduction from the solid surface. Conduction transfers heat from the planet core to its cooling surface layers. There is a net transfer of energy into space and the planet cools.

The situation isn't completely hypothetical: this how white dwarf stars cool.

If the atmosphere was hot enough then another way of cooling would be for the fastest moving atoms/molecules to be boiled off into space. This is only sustainable if the means exists to replenish the atmosphere from the surface below. Otherwise, the planet will end up with no atmosphere and its hot surface will simply radiate into space.

Comment: So the collisions between the atoms and molecules in the atmosphere are **not** elastic?

Comment: If the temperature of the atmosphere and the solid sphere are equal (at the moment of the "appearance" of the system), is the initial cooling caused only by radiation?

Comment: @descheleschilder An atmosphere with a finite temperature will always emit radiation. Energy states are populated according to Boltzmann factors. Radiative transitions follow. Collisions are not required.

Comment: So collisions between molecules don't emit energy (i.e. they are elastic)?

Comment: @descheleschilder I said collisions were not required, not that they were elastic. A collisional excitation is not elastic, but excitation can be radiative. And if the atmosphere doesn't absorb IR radiation from the planet, then the cooling takes place directly from the planet into space.

Answer (score -2):

I think because initially there is no difference in temperature between the atmosphere and the planet, the planet is radiating energy into its surroundings (just like the atmosphere, which is only possible if the collisions between the molecules are non-elastic, about which disagreement exists in the question "why gas molecules don't settle?" I still don't know how to make a direct link to the question, so if somebody would be so kind...) which is empty space and the atmosphere. Let's for simplicity assume the atmosphere is composed of molecules of only one kind. The atmosphere itself also radiates energy. Because of the radiation from the planet cools the planet down, heat conduction occurs between the planet and the atmosphere, which is cooled down more and more because the radiation from the planet cools it down more and more. So the temperature of the atmosphere cools down. Add to this the energy which is lost by radiation of the atmosphere and the planet with atmosphere cools down like a black body as anna v already said.The point of discussion stays if the atmosphere radiates away energy by collisions between molecules (assuming the temperature is low enough for electronic excitations not to occur), which is a discussion point in the question I referred to (in a clumsy way...).